# meta_query search using relation AND returns no result

Tags: wordpress

I have two meta values price and rooms, and need to get post with this two fields, but when I use 'relation' => 'AND', it does not work. If I change it to OR it works fine.

```
$args = array(
        'meta_query'=> array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'price',
                'compare' => '<=',
                'value' => intval($_GET['price']),
                'type' => 'numeric',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'rooms',           
                'value' => intval($_GET['rooms'])           
            )
        ) 
    );
```

Comment: What have you done to verify a post has this AND that value set? If it works with OR but not AND then it's a logic error somewhere which is hard for us SO users to debug with the information given.

Comment: I set correct values to metas!

Comment: You set the correct meta values in your post? How about your $_GET values? When you set price, so you include a `$`? Again, nobody can really debug this but you since we don't know how you're setting your meta, how your saving your meta, or what the `$_GET` values are.